# Can Blender be used on an Android device?

Tags: installation

Can the software be downloaded on an Android device?  If yes, then what is the process?

Comment: You may be interested in this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/33062/599

Comment: STEP 1: install GNURoot Debian and Hacker's Keyboard.

STEP 2: Launch Virtual Machine (computer button)

STEP 3: Touch the 3 dots button and switch to Input Track pad

STEP 4: Install blender by click the terminal and type: apt-get install blender

STEP 5: type:Y

STEP 6: When the install finished click at the wall screen and select exit

STEP 7: Launch again then click main screen and go to App >Graphic>Blender

STEP 8: Wait until it display frame placing, just click and wait until it in.

If nothing happen, you can uninstall and install again.

Comment: You can also use it from cloud: https://www.rollapp.com/app/blender . Or Remote Desktop with your own PC.

Comment: the simplest and easiest way to run blender 2.79b in android device https://youtu.be/9SedjSEv_iI

Comment: i think this video should it worked for me
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W_LW1M9ljj4

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sorry, there is no Android support at this time, and probably not ever. It would involve a massive coding effort for support and because blender is very cpu/gpu intensive, the devices that run it would make for a poor experience indeed.

Comment: Well said. Plus, one would need to pair a keyboard with it for it to be usable in any practical way. Maybe doable with a tablet, but with a phone it would be ridiculous. Just one more reason among many.

Comment: I think I heared of an Android Test Build... So I'm not quite sure if this answer is correct. But I think it wasn't fully usable due to the lack of a keyboard.

Comment: Hey, but there's a blenderplayer for Android. http://www.blendernation.com/2012/06/26/blenderplayer-for-android

Comment: I hadn't heard of this but it looks like quite an old project and not a version of blender but a port of the game engine player. Interesting though.

Answer (score 6):

In fact they have a version for Android.

Check this out.

https://www.blendernation.com/2015/02/12/using-blender-for-android/

Answer (score 4):

I'm running Blender 2.76b on KitKat Galaxy Tab 3 lite
8GB internal 1GB Ram

A little slow, but it's sufficient for simple designs.

1. Go to Google Play Store and install GNURoot Debian. You can download apk. Just make sure your internal memory free about 850MB to install.
2. Install Hacker's Keyboard
3. Launch Virtual Machine (computer button)
4. Touch the 3 dots button and switch to *Input Track pad* mode.
5. Install blender by click the terminal and enter `apt-get install blender`
6. Press <kbd>Y</kbd>.
7. When the terminal back to receive input state (install completed) click at the wall screen and select exit
8. Launch virtual machine then click main screen and go to *App -> Graphic -> Blender*
9. Wait until it display frame placing, just click and wait until it in.

If nothing happen after install blender and reboot the machine, or can't boot the virtual machine, you can uninstall and install agian (sometimes got unknown error)

You can install inkscape by entering `apt-get install inkscape`

[image]