# Older Version of Blender for ARM processors?

Tags: installation

I have been going at this for some time now,  I cant seem to compile blender from source due to some deprecated directives in cmake and jpeg_library, although there may be a way to do this that I am just unaware, following the guides on making from source did not work.  I am trying to simply install version 2.79, the newest version that will run, (for ARM) on Ubuntu Mate...the apt-get install seems to be set to the 2.82 package which cannot run on my hardware due to 2.8 and up using OpenGL 3.3 (Running Raspberry Pi 4b).. Does anyone know where I can download a prebuilt version for ARM processors?  Unfortunately it is not included in the repository...If anyone knows how I can install the older package via apt-get or some other way I would be appreciative?

Tried Stuff like:

sudo apt-get install blender= 2.79.b+dfsg0-7

to no avail, just

apt-cache policy blender
blender:
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 2.82.a+dfsg-1
Version table:
2.82.a+dfsg-1 500
500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/universe arm64 Packages

Comment: For clarification, no arm builds here: https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33015/can-blender-run-headless-on-an-arm-processor

Comment: Thanks susu, that link is how I found some of the older package names in the Debian repository links, unfortunately they all need to be compiled, thats also where I found the instructions for compiling from source: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender unfortunately CMAKE says some of the directives trying to be run are deprecated from that package.  I am not running a headless application either.  As to whether it can run, it works on Raspberry Pi OS because the package manger downloads 2.79.  Just trying to install a normal release of 2.79 for ARM

Comment: Can build previous versions from source. Checkout the branch, build the dependencies.

Comment: @batFinger Thanks, I have used: sudo apt-get install build-essential git subversion cmake libx11-dev libxxf86vm-dev libxcursor-dev libxi-dev libxrandr-dev libxinerama-dev libglew-dev   //  also install_deps.sh

Comment: cmake documentation said OPENJPEG_LIBRARY deprecated - make output: -- Could NOT find OpenEXR (missing: _openexr_LIBRARIES OPENEXR_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Could NOT find OpenJPEG (missing: OPENJPEG_LIBRARY OPENJPEG_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Could NOT find Spacenav (missing: SPACENAV_LIBRARY SPACENAV_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Could NOT find OpenImageIO (missing: OPENIMAGEIO_LIBRARY OPENIMAGEIO_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- OpenImageIO not found, disabling WITH_CYCLES
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:880 (message):
  Cycles requires WITH_OPENIMAGEIO, the library may not have been found.
  Configure OIIO or disable WITH_CYCLES

Answer (score 1):

You can run blender 2.82 on the Pi, with the following command:
`sudo apt install blender`
then:
`MESA_OPENGL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.3 blender`

But that's a hack, it's slow, and lighting doesn't work correctly.

On the plus side, you *can* compile blender 2.79 by running a modified version of the setup script and disabling cycles embree. To edit the setup script successfully, remove all mentions of sse, and replace all `-march=i386` flags with `-march=native`.